# AngularJS Function, difference between parameter with and without '$'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between

```
$scope.firstFunction = function($parameter) {
   //Any code
};
```

and

```
$scope.secondFunction = function(parameter) {
  //Any code
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference, just a naming convetion. Also built-in Angular modules are prefixed with '$' sign.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific as to what those parameters actually are. Do both versions of this code actually work?

Usually anything prefixed with $ is coming from angular such as $scope, $stateProvider so it SHOULD matter unless something is horribly misconfigurated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing but the name of `parameter`?

The only place in Angular, where parameters prepended with a `$` matters, are where the Dependency Injector works. For instance in Controllers, Services, Directives etc..

Comment: Thank you. I was just confused on how to use the parameters